# Weird bug that was biting my scalp

Tags: bugs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg6mG.jpg)

WHAT IS THIS?

[image]

Comment: I'd say that's a tick.

Comment: How big is it, where in the world are you, what climate, we need details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not agree that the remark from the bot is not right. I also asked for more information. Just a photo without further information is not much.

Comment: @ab2, write to the team, this discussion does not belong on a question on this site.

Comment: @Darren definitely not a tick. Spotted carapace, articulated legs… doesn't look a tick!